# Python rdflib - string to URIRef or Literal - inverse of .n3() method

Tags: python, rdflib

I'm using rdflib to work with semantic data, and want to serialise a triple to some minimal string value.

Given a triple `(s,p,o)`, I can use rdflib's `.n3()` method to return the string values representing the contents of s,p,o and join them together as a string.

```
" ".join([t.n3() for t in (s,p,o)])
```

This works whether the underlying terms are of type `URIRef` or `Literal`.

What I'd like to do next is the inverse, so given a series of strings like:

```
"<http://myonto.com/thing1> <http://myonto.com/prop1> <http://myonto.com/thing2>" 
"<http://myonto.com/thing1> <http://myonto.com/prop1> <2>"
```

I want a method that will allow me to convert these string terms that were generated by the `.n3()` method back into their original rdflib typed objects (either URIRef or Literal).

Something along the lines of:

```
s,p,o = [inverse_n3(t) for t in longform.split( )]
```

Looking at the documents, I can see this term --> n3 method, but not the inverse - is this something that exists, and if so can you point me at a document covering it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out rdflib has this exact function hidden away in its [rdflib.util](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/rdflib/util.html) library:

So I've ended up using:

```
from rdflib.util import from_n3

def n3_to_term(n3):
    return from_n3(n3.encode('unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape'))
```

enabling the line to perform the stated conversion.

```
s,p,o = [n3_to_term(t) for t in longform.split()]
```

There's some added details around serializing and deserializing to do with handling delimiters, quotes and escape characters but the core of the problem is dealt with by this [rdflib.util.from_n3](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.util.from_n3) function.